# eclipse JavaFx API version and runtime error

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

[image]

Everytime I try running my code I get this error message?

Comment: 1) Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) Please don't post photos of error messages - at the VERY least, take a screenshot. Better still, copy/paste or type the exception message *in the question*.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the `FXMLLoader` source code you'll find that warning message:

```
private void processValue() throws LoadException {
    ...
    // checking the version JavaFX API - print warning if not supported
    String defaultNSURI = xmlStreamReader.getNamespaceContext().getNamespaceURI("");
    if (defaultNSURI != null) {
        String nsVersion = defaultNSURI.substring(defaultNSURI.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        if (compareJFXVersions(JAVAFX_VERSION, nsVersion) < 0) {
            Logging.getJavaFXLogger().warning("Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version " +
                            nsVersion + " by JavaFX runtime of version " + JAVAFX_VERSION);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

As the comment says, it is checking if the current JRE JavaFX version (based on `System.getProperty("javafx.version")`) is lower than the version specified in the FXML file.

Scene Builder 8 sets that value whenever you create a new file in the so called name space FX value, based on the very same property:

```
private static final String NAME_SPACE_FX = "http://javafx.com/javafx/" + FXMLLoader.JAVAFX_VERSION;
```

If you run your project in other machine with an older version of JavaFX you will get this warning. Notice it is just a warning, not an error, that advises of the required JavaFX version.

Anyway, you can easily get rid of this warning, by editing the FXML file and lowering the required version:

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your java:

- Find and open the java control panel [Where is it on windows](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/win_controlpanel.xml);  [Where is it on Mac](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_controlpanel.xml);
- Find the Update tab inside the panel;
- Click on the Update Now button;